# Windows 10 Cumulative Update Failed to install - 0x80070003

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update

What might be causing the below Windows Update failure?

[image: Windows Update History]

**C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20200504194920.log**

```
2020-05-04 20:40:50, Info                  CBS    Perf: Doqe: Install started.
2020-05-04 20:40:50, Info                  CBS    Doqe: [Forward] Installing driver updates, Count 622
2020-05-04 20:40:51, Info                  CBS    Progress: UI message updated. Operation type: Update. Stage: 0 out of 0. Percent progress: 7.
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    DriverUpdateInstallUpdates failed [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Doqe: Failed installing driver updates [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Perf: Doqe: Install ended.
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Failed installing driver updates [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Error                 CBS    Shtd: Failed while processing non-critical driver operations queue. [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Shtd: Rolling back KTM, because drivers failed.
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    SetProgressMessage: progressMessageStage: 4, ExecuteState: CbsExecuteStatePrimitives, SubStage: 0
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Progress: UI message updated. Operation type: Update. Stage: 0 out of 0. Temporary Rollback.
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Shtd: progress thread terminating. [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Shtd: progress thread terminated normally
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Doqe: Unlocking driver updates, Count 1336
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Simplifying Winlogon CreateSession notifications
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Shtd: Shutdown processing complete.
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Failed to call Shutdown Processing on Worker process. [HRESULT = 0x80070003]
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Failed to execute shutdown processing. [HRESULT = 0x80070003]
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Ending the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller finalization.
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Stopping notify server
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Unloading SysNotify DLL
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Lock: Lock removed: WinlogonNotifyLock, level: 8, total lock:6
2020-05-04 20:40:52, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller finalization.
```

**C:\Windows\INF\setupapi.dev.log**

```
[Device Install Log]
     OS Version = 10.0.18363
     Service Pack = 0.0
     Suite = 0x0100
     ProductType = 1
     Architecture = amd64

[BeginLog]

[Boot Session: 2020/05/04 19:47:49.500]

>>>  [Install Driver Updates]
>>>  Section start 2020/05/04 20:40:50.923
      cmd: C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.772_none_5f13f94c58ff41d3\TiWorker.exe -Embedding
     sto: Image State        = Specialized
     sto: Image Architecture = amd64
     sto: Image OS Version   = 10.0.18363
     sto: Image Product Type = WinNT
     sto: Transaction        = CbsDriversAndPrimitives
     sto: Driver Updates     = 622
!    inf: Unable to load INF: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpsamd.inf_amd64_0784fd3ef0d7ec93\hpsamd.inf'(00000003)
!    inf: Error 3: The system cannot find the path specified.
!!!  inf: Invalid INF 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpsamd.inf_amd64_0784fd3ef0d7ec93\hpsamd.inf', parsing error on line 0. Code = 1002
!!!  sto: Failed to get version info for driver update 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpsamd.inf_amd64_0784fd3ef0d7ec93\hpsamd.inf'. Error = 0x00000003
<<<  Section end 2020/05/04 20:40:52.174
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0x00000003)]
```

Comment: They might be superseded by a feature update. What happens if you download the KB installer manually and run it for say KB4550945? There's also this comment on the page for that KB "Microsoft strongly recommends you install the latest servicing stack update (SSU) for your operating system before installing the latest cumulative update (LCU). SSUs improve the reliability of the update process to mitigate potential issues while installing the LCU."

Comment: @spikey_richie - The update in question is the servicing stack update.  Given that KB4550945 was released recently it hasn’t been superseded by any update.  I have submitted an answer to this exact problem in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error code 0x80070003 while upgrading windows 10 from 1809 to 1909](https://superuser.com/questions/1511648/error-code-0x80070003-while-upgrading-windows-10-from-1809-to-1909)

Comment: *hpsamd.inf* is a Microsoft system driver, I would use DISM, and attempt to repair any damage.  The update is failing when it attempts to determine information on the driver.

Comment: SetupDiag might provide more information, if running DISM, doesn’t resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the below folder from another machine and the Windows Update then completed successfully.

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpsamd.inf_amd64_0784fd3ef0d7ec93
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, only the driver was different in my case:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\xusb22.inf_amd64_d0f2fd4c931f4672\xusb22.inf
```

I looked at some other Windows 10 PCs around but the did not have that exact path, instead they had `xusb22.inf_amd64_d80349221fa8b78c` which is different.

I also noticed the following entries in the same `C:\Windows\INF\setupapi.dev.log` log:

```
     sto: {Stage Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_dual_xusb22.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_06db87eae10b8df5\xusb22.inf} 18:55:32.648
!    sto:      Driver package already imported as 'xusb22.inf' (C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\xusb22.inf_amd64_d0f2fd4c931f4672\xusb22.inf).
```

I manually created the `C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\xusb22.inf_amd64_d0f2fd4c931f4672\` folder and I copied the contents of `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_dual_xusb22.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_06db87eae10b8df5\` there.

This seems to have cleared this condition out for me.